# perl/cgi script not found error 404 apache2

Tags: perl, apache2, cgi, http-status-code-404

I have a perl script in /var/cgi-bin directory which executes normally with the url:

localhost/cgi-bin/filename.pl

but when i call the same file through a html file the loaclhost server return a 404 not found error.

code:
html file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"encoding="utf-8"?>
<html>
            <head>
                            <title>light bulbsr form</title>
            </head>
            <body>

<form action="/cgi-bin/bulbs.pl" method="POST">

user name<input type="text" name="myname" size="30"/><br>

select the items:<br>

<input type="checkbox" name="b" value="2.39" /> four100 watt light bulbs  </br>
<input type="checkbox" name="b" value="4.29">  eight 100 watt light bulbs </br>
<input type="checkbox" name="b" value="3.95">  four 100 watt  long life bulbs </br>
<input type="checkbox" name="b" value="7.49"> eight100 watt  long life bulbs </br>

Select the mode of the payment:</br>

<input type ="radio" name="paymode" value="visa" checked="checked"/>Visa<br>
<input type ="radio" name="paymode" value="Master card"/>Master card<br>
<input type ="radio" name="paymode" value="Discover"/>Discover<br>

                            <input type="submit" value="submit order"/>
                            <input type="reset" value="Clear the form"/>
            </body>
</html>
```

perl file:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use CGI qw(:standard);
use strict;


print header(),start_html ("Bill ");
print p("The total cost:0");br();
print end_html;
```

the apache2 000-default.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/cgi-bin/
     <Directory "/var/cgi-bin/">
             AllowOverride None
             Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
             Require all granted
     </Directory>
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: what's the URL of the HTML document? You probably need `cgi-bin/filename.pl` or `/cgi-bin/filename.pl` because your HTML file is not in the `cgi-bin` directory.

Comment: I hope this is a learning exercise. You're not going to pick up credit card numbers with this, are you?

Comment: Yes,this is a learning exercise. Plz help!!

Comment: You've said the cgi-bin is in `/var/cgi-bin`. Where is the HMTL file?

Comment: the html file is in /var/www/html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form action is "filename.pl". That means the web server will look for "filename.pl" in the same directory as the HTML page containing the form. And that's not where it it. You probably want the full path.

```
<form action="/cgi-bin/filename.pl">
```

Comment: Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40654525/edit) to include more details. Where is the HTML page that includes this form? Where is your CGI directory? What errors are you getting in the web server error log?

Comment: Solved!
the problem was with the apache server.Once i restarted the system your solution worked.Thanks!!